# Angular Show loader on fetching data from httpclient.get

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I want to know how ill add loader when data is fetching from api. I need loader until the data comes .

```
this.clientData = this.httpClient.get(url,{responseType: 'json'}).
  subscribe(data => {
   //here the loader come i think
  console.log(data);
  this.data = data.records;
 }
```

and when data is fetched the loader closed. If possible by bootstrap im also using bootstrap in application.

Comment: Can you show the bootstrap code? actually, it is done with one boolean value!

Comment: there is a lot of doc about it. Basically you wire a service in charge of showing/hiding the loader with an interceptor. See https://firstclassjs.com/display-a-loader-on-every-http-request-using-interceptor-in-angular-7/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is the best way to do this but I guess it will work

```
async getCall() {
  // Show loader here
  this.showLoader = true;

  this.clientData = await this.httpClient.get(url,{responseType: 'json'}).toPromise();

  // Hide Loader here
  this.showLoader = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**component**

```
this.IsLoading = true;
    this.httpClient.get(url,{responseType: 'json'}).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.data = res.records;
        console.log(res);
      },
      error => { },
      () => (this.IsLoading = false)
    );
  }
```

**html file**

```
<div class="content" [appSpinner]="IsLoading">
/*show content*/
</div>
```

and add `spinner` as `directive`

OR if you don't want to use directive, you can simply use

```
<div class="content" *ngIf="IsLoading">
/***/
</div>
```

Comment: not showing any spinner. Or i need to add spinner ?

Comment: You need to add spinner